# Disable or enable text input forms when radio buttons are clicked, using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have multiple text inputs, and Ive added a class to them called 'bankinput'. I have two radio buttons generated by asp.net helpers, though I dont think it has anything to do with that. I've checked the generated html and they have as ids, respectively, 'id="Cheque"' and 'id="Draft"'.
For the sake of completion, let me show the generated html:

```
<label for="Cheque"> <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-
required="The Payment Mode field is required." id="Cheque" name="IsCheque" 
type="radio" value="true">Cheque</label>
<label for="Draft"><input id="Draft" name="IsCheque" type="radio" 
 value="false"> Draft </label>
```

I want the text boxes with the aforementioned class to be disabled when I click the Cheque radio box and enabled when I click Draft.
I did some searching and and found some JS that should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#Cheque').change(function () {
        disable();
    });
    $('#Draft').change(function () {
        enable();
    });
    function disable() {
        $('.bankinput').prop('disabled', true);
    };
    function enable() {
        $('.bankinput').removeAttr('disabled');
    };

});   
</script>
```

Problem is, it doesnt do anything. Nothing happens and breakpoints set in there are never triggered except when the document loads. I'm not great with JS so it could be anything as far as I'm concerned.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I've just copied your code to a JSFiddle, and it seems to work just fine https://jsfiddle.net/asmwf86m/

I would suggest that you don't set checked on the Cheque input, this way you force the user to make a choice, and also ensures the change event is fired

Comment: I'm sure it doesnt work in my code, so it must be something else i havent included. I dont know what to look at

Comment: As FBlade answered, possibly the buttons are loaded in dynamically after your Javascript has run.. If that's the case, you'll need to make use of a delegated event handler, which has been detailed in FBlade's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look likes buttons generated by asp.net helpers are loaded after script...

try something like:

```
....
$(document).on('change', '#Cheque', function(){
     disable();
});
....
```

Answer (score 0):

FBBlade may be on to something but here's what I ended up doing:

```
 <label for="Cheque">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsCheque, "true", new { @id = 
      "Cheque", onchange = "disable()" })
Cheque
 </label>
<label for="Draft">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsCheque, "false", new { @id = 
      "Draft", onchange = "enable()" })
    Draft 
</label>
```

so the big change was setting the onchange event handler to my prescribed functions. I'm guessing this ends up being the same as what FBBlade posted. Though now that I think about, the asp.net helpers and such simply change what code is generated, I dont see why that would load any differently. The browser shouldnt even know the difference by the time the html gets to it....